# Silverstripe: Unable to delete pages from back end

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

Hi guys I can't seem to be able to delete pages from the admin back end. Can anyone help me understand why this is?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you select `Archive` and press `Go`?

Comment: It just archives the page and when I view it, it says "This page is archived"

Comment: `Unpublish` will delete the page from the live version of the site. `Archive` will delete the page from the draft version of the site. Doing both will delete the page from both the draft and live version of the site. The page still exists in the database, and can be restore, but is technically deleted as far as SilverStripe will allow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Archiving is the  new way to delete pages in SilverStripe 3.2

Deleting pages never actually deleted them in older versions of the CMS and this wording was often confusing for CMS users because they could then go and see these "deleted" pages later (by browsing deleted pages).

Another issue commonly encountered was that there was little clarity between Delete from draft and delete from live, so these have basically been removed and instead we now have "Archive" (delete from both live and draft and hide away) or "unpublish" (delete from live).

The wording and behaviour was updated to make things simpler as often the need to delete from live but NOT from draft was very limited.

The old behaviour can be brought back by changing the config setting like so:

```
CMSMain:
  enabled_legacy_actions:
    - CMSBatchAction_DeleteFromLive
    - CMSBatchAction_Delete
```

You can read more about the discussion around this on the PR that brought in the changes: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/4189 and https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/pull/1203

Further upgrade guidance here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/changelogs/3.2.0/#revert-to-legacy-cms-page-actions

Original ticket: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/issues/631

Comment: Great response. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete the page by browsing into it first.

You are currently attempting to perform a batch action - intended for selecting a large number of pages to perform an action to at once. It seems that 'delete' has perhaps been renamed to 'archive' (since it is possible to restore 'deleted' pages, it would make more sense).

You can see more information here: https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/creating_pages_and_content/pages/